# { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server on first connect [MongoError: bad auth : Authentication failed.]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've just created a new cluster with a new db and a new collection. Seemed to be my connection/network but I've been able to successfully entered content into another cluster.

```
    let sendToDb = (dataObj) => {
  MongoClient.connect(connectionURL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  }, (error, client) => {
    if(error){
      return console.log(error);
    }
    const db = client.db(databaseName);
    db.collection("rbg_values").insertOne({
      entry: dataObj
    }, (error, result) => {
      if(error){
        return console.log("unable to insert in the ford_twitter");
      }
      console.log("Data successfully inserted");
    })
  })
}
```

This is the code I'm using. Adding it here but I'm not sure it's the issue.

[image]

This is the network access settings of the cluster.

[image]

As you can see here, the cluster is called: OROBOROGRAM.

However, the connection URL they give me is with the string: `gene` (how the cluster was named before I renamed it) as following:

```
var uri = "mongodb://gene:<password>@cluster0-shard-00-00.1jykx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.1jykx.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.1jykx.mongodb.net:27017/<dbname>?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-7yzqv2-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

I've tried changing this with the new name but I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user Gene's password was not the same as mine - I had to delete it and add myself into the Database Access user list.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to replace the < password > in the uri with the password you used for your mongoDB account.

Comment: Yes I did that. the <password> is replaced for my password (without  the "<" + ">"), same for the db